# Mysql Subquery returns more than 1 row from many databases

Tags: mysql, sql

The query doesn't work.
i want to insert into durance all vnum from player.item_proto

how can i do that?

```
INSERT INTO durance (vnum, max_durance, price_per_durance)
VALUES(
    (SELECT vnum 
     FROM player.item_proto 
     WHERE limitvalue0 >= 10 
     AND type in (1,2)), 
    100, 50)
```

error: 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `values`, use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO durance(vnum, max_durance, price_per_durance)
    select vnum, 100, 50
    from player.item_proto
    where limitvalue0 >= 10 and type in (1,2);
```

This assumes that you actually want to insert all the matching rows into `durance`.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the term `VALUES`
the syntax is `INSERT INTO table (columns) SELECT ... FROM ...`